# An "alternating" sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $_1, _2, ..., _$ be positive real numbers satisfying $_{−1} ≤ _{} ≤ 2_{−1}$ for any $k \geq 2$. Prove that we can choose variables $_1, _2, ..., _ \in \{−1, +1\}$ such that $0 \leq _1_1 + _2_2 + ⋯ + __ \leq _1$

I've tried using induction:

$P(n)$: we can choose variables $_1, _2, ..., _ \in \{−1, +1\}$ such that $0 \leq _1_1 + _2_2 + ⋯ + __ \leq _1$

Now suppose $P(n-1)$ true and try to prove $P(n)$

I think to let $t_1 = x_1, t_2 = x_2, ... t_{n-2}=x_{n-2}, t_{n-1} = x_n - x_{n-1}$ and try to use P(n-1).

$t_{n-1}$ verifies $t_{n-1} \leq 2t_{n-2} \iff x_n - x_{n-1} \leq 2x_{n-2}$ which is true because
$x_n \leq 2x_{n-1} \leq x_{n-1} + 2x_{n-2}$ but I can't prove $t_{n-2} \leq t_{n-1}$.

I've also tried with $t_1 := x_2 - x_1 , ... , t_n := x_n - x_{n-1}$ but without success.
Is this way a good way? Any hints or help is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to insert $ x_n - x_{n-1} $ at the end of the sequence, you just have to insert it wherever is suitable.

Let me do an explicit example. Say the sequence we have is

$$ 3, 3, 5, 9, 11 $$

Now, $ 11-9 = 2 $ is obviously not a number we can put at the end, so we put it at the start and get

$$ (11-9), 3, 3, 5 $$

Likewise, we put $ 5-3 = 2 $ at the start to get

$$ (5-3), (11-9), 3 $$

Iterating this two more times:

$$ 3 - (11-9), (5-3) $$

$$ (5-3) - (3 - (11-9)) = -3 -3 + 5 - 9 + 11 = 1 $$

which satisfies the condition as $ 1 \leq 3 $. Does this concrete example give you any ideas on how to complete your proof by induction?

Comment: Hmm. I think I understand your example. But I don't know how I can continue the proof

Comment: I think I got it. So, let $t = x_n - x_{n-1}$ . We need to find an $i \in {1,...n-2}$ such that $t \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]$. This $i$ exists, and then we have $x_{i} \leq t \leq 2 x_{i}$ and $t \leq x_{i+1} \leq 2t$, so we can apply $P(n-1)$. It's ok?

Comment: @MathLearner That's right.